# Java process using "/dev/random" despite specifying "/dev/urandom" in "java.security.egd"

Tags: java, random

I am running a java process where we are passing JVM parameter as `-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom`

But when i used Java flight recorder, i can see its still using file `/dev/random`

[image]

Can someone please advise if something is wrong with the setup.

Edit:

Checked further, this issue started occuring after adding a call to `SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(bytes);`

Comment: How do you know what Java class is reading `/dev/random`?

Comment: @chrylis: I did the flight recording using java mission control and have pasted the screenshot which shows that IO operations are happening on on "/dev/random" rather than "/dev/urandom"

Comment: That's not what I asked. You obviously *are* in fact getting access to `/dev/random`, but what class is doing it?

Comment: @chrylis: I dont know which class, is there a way to find it ? But i am connecting to Oracle DB, so most likely its jdbc driver.

Comment: @chrylis : Its caused by api SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(bytes);”

Comment: This is an extremely old problem.  `/dev/random` is special-cased in the code, try using `/dev/./random` which bypasses the explicit test.  I used to have a link to the bug in the Java database but cannot find it right now.  If I find it I'll post an answer.

Comment: I remembered it backwards in my answer.  Then I had a vague recollection of having answered this before, so I searched my old answers and found it.  I've deleted my answer and marked this question a duplicate of the other one (but still gave you the upvote)  This "feature" bites people occasionally and having a second way to find it in SO is valuable.